# Delete record from my table in the database

Tags: oracle10g, oracleforms

I want to delete record from table in my forms and from table in database ...
this is my code:

```
if /*condition*/ then 

 delete_record;

 commit;

end if;
```

Note: I get this error: `FRM-40508 : ORACLE error: unable to INSERT record`

But ,only record at the forms 's deleted !!! but in the database already exist !!!

Comment: That FRM-40508 is telling you that Forms thinks it needs to insert the record (i.e. the record was not queried from the database). When it tries to run the insert, it is getting an error. You need to investigate what that error is. e.g. examine DBMS_ERROR_TEXT

Comment: By the way, your question is hard to understand, especially "But ,only record at the form 's deleted !!!" which is too ungrammatical to parse.

Comment: Also, it might help to know which trigger that code gets executed from.

Comment: From your question it is very hard to understand. But I think you trying to insert data with same unique information. Do you want to update or delete data in table and the store new?

Answer (score 0):

First of all FRM-xxxx error means that is an Oracle forms error and not a database error. 
To be sure, try the show-error key sequence (in my setup is Ctrl+Shift+E) to see if there is also an oracle error.
delete_record is a restricted procedure, so cannot call it from some WHEN- or POST- or PRE- triggers. Can you tell us where is this code located?